# Thread 6:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 1, dress=0x8)

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, objective-c++, image-recognition

I am using iPhone5s to do black object tracking: but often meet with

```
Thread 6:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 1, dress=0x8)
```

and then my App quit suddenly. Could anyone tell me why this happen?

this error happens at :

```
template<typename _Tp> inline
_Tp Rect_<_Tp>::area() const
{
    return width * height; //Thread 6:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 1, dress=0x8)
}
//this method is in types.hp in latest opencv framework
```

my colored object recognition code is as below:

```
#pragma mark - Protocol CvVideoCameraDelegate
#ifdef __cplusplus
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat &)image{
   Mat imageCopy,imageCopy2;
   cvtColor(image, imageCopy, COLOR_BGRA2BGR);

   cvtColor(imageCopy, imageCopy2, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
   //smooth the image
   GaussianBlur(imageCopy2, imageCopy, cv::Size(5,5),0, 0);

   cv::inRange(imageCopy, cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0), cv::Scalar(180,255,30,0),     
   imageCopy2);    

/*****************************find the contour of the detected area abd draw  it***********************************/
//2-D point to store countour
std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point>> contour1;
//do opening on the binary thresholded image

   int erosionSize = 3;
   Mat erodeElement =    
   getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE,cv::Size(2*erosionSize+1,2* erosionSize+1), cv::Point(erosionSize,erosionSize));
   erode(imageCopy2, imageCopy2, erodeElement);
   dilate(imageCopy2, imageCopy2, erodeElement);

   //Acual line to find the contour
   cv::findContours(imageCopy2, contour1, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

   //set the color used to draw the conotour
   Scalar color1 = Scalar(50,50,50);

  //loop the contour to draw the contour
  for(int i=0; i< contour1.size(); i++){
     drawContours(image, contour1, i, color1);
  }
  /******END*****/

/****************************find the contour of the detected area abd draw  it***********************************/
/****************************Appproximate the contour to polygon && get bounded Rectangle and Circle*************/
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours_poly(contour1.size());
std::vector<cv::Rect> boundedRect(contour1.size());
std::vector<cv::Point2f> circleCenter(contour1.size());
std::vector<float> circleRadius(contour1.size());

for (int i=0; i< contour1.size(); i++){
    approxPolyDP(Mat(contour1[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
    boundedRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));
    minEnclosingCircle((Mat)contours_poly[i], circleCenter[i], circleRadius[i]);

}
/******END*******/
/*****************************draw the rectangle for detected area ***********************************************/
Scalar recColor = Scalar(121,200,60);
Scalar fontColor = Scalar(0,0,225);
//find the largest contour
int largestContourIndex=0;
for (int i=0; i<contour1.size(); i++){
    if(boundedRect[i].area()> boundedRect[largestContourIndex].area())
        largestContourIndex=i;
}

int j=largestContourIndex;
if(boundedRect[j].area()>40){
    rectangle(image, boundedRect[j].tl(), boundedRect[j].br(), recColor);
    //show text at tl corner
    cv::Point fontPoint = boundedRect[j].tl();
    putText(image, "Black", fontPoint, FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3, fontColor);    
    }


//    cvtColor(imageCopy, image, COLOR_HLS2BGR);
}
#endif
```

Comment: one of your Rect_ instance is null pointer. if this problem always occur, you can debug it and see what's wrong

Comment: I only have a bounding Rect for each contour. and none of them is a none pointer. The thing I just notice is that when there is none black object in camera, this error occur. Oh, at that point , the contour does  not exist, Are you saying there will be some null points then?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figure out why :
Just as @SolaWing said, there exist some null pointer. For future Viewers,  just want to make it more clear:

**Problem is at the following code:**

```
if(boundedRect[j].area()>40){
rectangle(image, boundedRect[j].tl(), boundedRect[j].br(), recColor);
//show text at tl corner
cv::Point fontPoint = boundedRect[j].tl();
putText(image, "Black", fontPoint, FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3, fontColor);    
}
```

for this block of code, it already assume that there always exist detected areas, But Actually, when there is no target area in front of Phone Camera, the **contour.size()**  is zero,  that being said, for `std::vector<cv::Rect> boundedRect(contour1.size());` boundedRect is null pointer,  then there will be a problem when I use  `if(boundedRect[j].area()>40){}`, which is using first pointer of the null pointer.